# Using "toast notification" in winform or WPF

Tags: c#, windows, toast, notifyicon

I'd like to use a scrollbar like the one who shows up if you press the sound symbol on windows 10.

In my research I only found toast notification or notifyicon which I think isn't the right thing.

Picture:

[image: Scrollbar]

Do I overlooked something? Is this even possible in winform or WPF? and does someone know the right name for that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a slider control possibly? http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/Slidervaluechangedevent.htm

Comment: the one windows shows is a custom one. But you can do the same with some work required to make the same look transparent. What you want to do is simply popup a `Form` or a `Window` on the click of the notify icon. On that `Form` or `Window` you can put any control you want.

Comment: @Franck Thanks for the fast reply. The form or window is a excellent idea, thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/slider